# How to add labels to an already trained Yolo model?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, transfer-learning, yolo

I'm learning ML and I'm exploring object detection and classification. I discovered Yolo few months ago and it's impressively efficient and accurate. There are several pre-trained Yolo models on the web that can handle most of everyday objects.

Now, I'd like to train a Yolo model with custom objects. However... I want to keep already learned labels in the model. I would like to **add new labels in the model**, not to replace them. There are lot of tutorials that explain very well how to use custom labels from a pre-trained model but I did not find anything about increasing the number of classes inside a pre-trained model.

I barely found [a discussion on a GitHub about this](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/1088#issuecomment-505383951) and the only solution was to train again all existing labels along with the new ones. I think this is quite tedious. I've read there is a mechanism called transfer learning but I'm not sure how this can be applied to add new labels in a model.

Comment: What version of YOLO are you planning to use?

Comment: I'm planning to use YOLOv3 from AlexeyAB/darknet.